# How do I exclude a single menu item from the sitemap?

Tags: 7, navigation

In my sitemap, I am displaying main menu and footer menu, but as per requirement I don't want a specific menu item to display in the sitemap. My footer menu has following items:

- industrial
- mechanics
- sports

Is there a way not to add *mechanics* to the sitemap?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to consider the approach described in [comment # 1 in issue # 985138](https://www.drupal.org/node/985138#comment-9362061) (for D7), which is like so:

```
/**
* Override site_map function
*/
function hide_in_sitemap_preprocess_site_map(&$variables) {
  $mids = variable_get('site_map_show_menus', array());
  $output = '';
  if ($mids) {
    foreach ($mids as $mid) {
      $menu = menu_load($mid);
      // Use menu_tree_all_data to retrieve the expanded tree.
      $tree = menu_tree_all_data($mid);
        foreach ($tree as $branch => $value) {
          if ($value["link"]["options"]["hide_in_sitemap"]) {
            unset($tree[$branch]);
        }
      }

      if (module_exists('i18nmenu')) {
        i18nmenu_localize_tree($tree);
      }
      $menu_display = _site_map_menu_tree_output($tree);
      $rendered = drupal_render($menu_display);

      if (!empty($menu_display)) {
        $title = $menu['title'];
          $vars = array( 'title' => $title,
                        'content' => $rendered);
        $output .= theme('site_map_box', $vars);
      }
    }
  }
  $variables["menus"] = $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *just* don't want to ***display*** the link, a quick and dirty workaround with a little help from css could look like this:

```
li.menu-id_number  {
    display:none;
}
```

so for a page of content type "sitemap" and a menu link with an id number of "1234" this could look like this:

```
.page-sitemap li.menu-1234  {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [Menu Item visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility) module.

> This module exposes configurable and extendable visibility settings
>   for menu links. For example, if you want to create a 'My account' link
>   that points to /user, both anonymous and registered users have access
>   to the /user path, so both will see the link, even if anonymous users
>   do not technically have an account. Using this module will allow you
>   to only have your 'My account' link visible to registered users, and
>   hide it from anonymous users.

Comment: Thanku @NishantP, if I used this to hide a specific item then it will be hidden from my main menu too whereas I need to only hide it from sitemap display..Strange client requirement :(

Comment: No by using this module you can hide item on particular page.

Comment: It gives me visibility options for only roles, `anonymous user`, `authenticate user` then how can I exclude it only from sitemap page. If a selected anyone option then it will excluded from my main menu too.